# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value

Tags: python, django, heroku

I know people asked similar question before. But it's all about the engine value. does any one know how do I solve this error with the NAME value? I deployed to heroku and everything works fine. however, in local, it gives me this error
here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/Google Drive/heroku/luxingnan/views.py" in home
  17.         return render(request,'luxingnan/home.html',{'auth_form':auth_form, 'user_form':user_form,'cars':cars,'next_url': '/',})
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  328.             if match:
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  170.         return type(self).__bool__(self)
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __bool__
  166.         self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  827.         cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in cursor
  162.             cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in _cursor
  135.         self.ensure_connection()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  130.                 self.connect()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in connect
  118.         conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
File "/Users/qiaoweiliu/.virtualenvs/heroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in get_connection_params
  154.                 "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /
Exception Value: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
```

and here is my setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

is enough. And if you want to use `django_postgrespool`, you can edit it above.

But your following lines:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'
```

is just overwriting the above standard `DATABASE` settings. So you need to delete those 2 lines (or define it via `dj_database_url` and remove the above snippet).

Comment: It works. But I prefer working with the same database in dev and production. Is there another way? This is confusing to me because my DATABASE_URL contains username, password and database name, dj_database_url just couldn't pick up the database name

Comment: Just set the `DATABASE` didn't let you working with the same database in dev and production? I did this and it worked

Answer (score 3):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

import dj_database_url

db_config = dj_database_url.config()
if db_config:
    DATABASES['default'] =  db_config
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this tips

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was storing the whole DB url with password in an environment variable. I had set the password to contain `@` which messed with the parsing of the rest of the string, therefore not detecting the name parameter. Just changed the password to not include any `@` symbols.