# Getting Database is improperly configured .Please supply the name value error

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I come across this question [settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811971/settings-databases-is-improperly-configured-please-supply-the-name-value) but it doesn't worked for me.

On applying python manage.py makemigrations,I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in  execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 106, in handle
loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 276, in check_consistent_history
applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
self.ensure_schema()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in cursor
cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 170, in connect
conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
File "/home/rishav/EvalAI/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 158, in get_connection_params
"settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
```

My dev database

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'evalai',
    'USER': 'rishav',
    'PASSWORD': 'rishav',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5432,
  }
 }
```

And the prod database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME', ""),
    'USER': os.environ.get('RDS_USERNAME', ""),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('RDS_PASSWORD', ""),
    'HOST': os.environ.get('RDS_HOSTNAME', ""),
    'PORT': os.environ.get('RDS_PORT', ""),
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You haven't explained how you're applying those dev and prod configs.

Comment: Actually its an open source project to which I am trying to contribute

Comment: But what is the code that determines which of those two DATABASES settings to use?

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance but I am unaware of it.This is the project I am trying to contribute https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI

Comment: I just found that in my prod file Debug=False.Does this means that it will be used when it is deployed and dev.py will be used ,when we are building it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your environment variable(s) in production may not be set -- I suspect this is what's happening.

Log into your production server(s) and ensure that your Django process has access to `RDS_DB_NAME`, `RDS_USERNAME`, etc. as environment variables.

**ALSO**: If you're having problems, you might want to try hard-coding fake credentials instead of using environment variables. This will at least get you to the next error, which should say invalid credentials or something similar. This will confirm that environment variables are the issue and need to be fixed.

**UPDATE**: If you want to try hardcoding credentials, do something like this for your production database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'test',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5432,
  }
}
```

This will 'hardcode' your fake credentials. You can then deploy this application and see what error you're getting.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance,but could you tell me how to ensure django has access to environment variables

Comment: If you log into your server that's running the Django project, then log in as the user account under which the Django app runs, you can view environment variables on the command line by using the `$ echo RDS_DB_NAME` syntax. If you don't see the value there, it means the environment variable does NOT exist.

Comment: it is printing the same value which I am echoeing

Comment: Check my post, try what I mentioned in the ALSO section.

Comment: Ok, just updated my post again with info about hardcoding your credentials to test.

Comment: Well,it worked ,I changed the user-name and password to my system's password and now I am not getting the error

Comment: but now manage.py migrate is not applying migrations.It is showing no migrations to apply

Comment: You might want to create a separate thread for the migration stuff, that is likely a different problem!

Comment: Okay allow me to figure it out.Thank a lot for your help